# Forcing an intercept with geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking to make a comparison graph between two variables, overlapping the `geom_smooth()` of the two products. The theory of the measurements force to have the starting point a `(x=0; y=0)` but when I make the graph, the blue regression line created with `geom_smooth()` doesn't pass over the coordinate `(0;0)`. Is it possible for this `geom_smooth()` to be fixed at the specific defined coordinates for the first point (0;0)?

Below the code:

```
library(ggplot2)

RawData <- data.frame(
  "Time" = c(0, 3, 6, 9, 24, 30, 34, 48, 57, 0, 3, 6, 9, 24, 30, 34, 48, 57), 
  "Curing" = c(0, 11.36, 31.81, 34.09, 75, 86.36, 97.7, 100, 100, 0, 77.5, 92, 95, 98, 100, 100, 100, 100), 
  "Grade" = c("Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B"))

attach(RawData)

Graph <- ggplot(data=RawData, aes(x=`Time`, y=`Curing`, col=Grade)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Grade), shape = 1, size = 2.5) + 
  geom_smooth(level=0.50, span = 0.9999999999) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#f92410','#644196')) + 
  xlab("Tempo espresso in ore") + 
  ylab("% Di reticolazione") + 
  labs(color='') + 
  theme(legend.justification = "top")

Graph + geom_rug(aes(color = Grade))
```

[image]

Thank you in advance for every eventual help!!

Comment: There was a mistake in the coide, I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several smoothing methods available for `geom_smooth`. For GLM/LM/GAMs you can explicitly specify a formula with intercept zero, e.g `geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~x+0)`. This doesn't work for loess, which is the default method in `geom_smooth` for small datasets (N<1,000), presumably because it fits locally.

In this case, the example uses the loess smoothing method, so to force the fit through zero you can give a very high weighting to the point `(0,0)` in your dataset for each group by using the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)

RawData <- data.frame("Time" = c(0, 3, 6, 9, 24, 30, 34, 48, 57, 0, 3, 6, 9, 24, 30, 34, 48, 57), "Curing" = c(0, 11.36, 31.81, 34.09, 75, 86.36, 97.7, 100, 100, 0, 77.5, 92, 95, 98, 100, 100, 100, 100), "Grade" = c("Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B"))

RawData$weight  = ifelse(RawData$Time==0, 1000, 1)

Graph <- ggplot(data=RawData, aes(x=`Time`, y=`Curing`, col=Grade)) + geom_point(aes(color = Grade), shape = 1, size = 2.5) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(weight=weight), level=0.50, span = 0.9999999999) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#f92410','#644196')) + xlab("Tempo espresso in ore") + ylab("% Di reticolazione") + labs(color='') + theme(legend.justification = "top")
Graph + geom_rug(aes(color = Grade))
```

This forces the modelled fit to go very close to the origin, giving the required plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Miff! It works and it is fine. You helped me a lot!!

Comment: Whereas this should work very fine with flexible curve such as loess, with a GLM that can actually make a big difference. Any update on the possibility to force intercept to nil (like done with GLM using "+0" in the formula)?

Comment: @yeahman269 Hopefully the additional paragraph at the start now covers this case.

Comment: Great thanks! Was not aware of it!