# How to force regression line to start from 100?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(DTT_Half, aes(x = Time.in.minutes, y = Percentage.of.DTT)) + 
  geom_point() + 
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,105), xlim = c(0, 10.5)) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  stat_regline_equation(label.y = 100, label.x = 7.5, 
                        aes(label = ..eq.label..))
```

[image: Regression line not starting from 100]

I want the regression line to start from 0,100 and this should be reflected in the equation of the line displayed.

I tried setting the formula in the stat_smooth function to various equations but none of them worked out.

Comment: You can fit a model without an intercept and [use the `offset` argument to set it to whatever value you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7334622/903061). I would be surprised if `ggpubr::stat_regline_equation` knows how to handle this case, you may need to edit the equation accordingly.

Comment: You can force the line to go through 100 [Forcing an intercept with geom_smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65716693/forcing-an-intercept-with-geom-smooth), but as @GregorThomas said, I am also not sure if `ggpubr` can handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this with `ggplot2` is a bit tricky; I have a solution, although maybe not the one you want.

- the most natural way to do this would be to specify the formula as `y ~ x + 0 + offset(100)` (the `0` suppresses the intercept [would force the regression through 0 if no offset were supplied, the `offset(100)` adds 100), but I couldn't figure out a way to pass the offset information through `ggplot` in the right way (it needs to be a vector of 100s of the right length ...)
- you can do this with the [weights trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65716693/forcing-an-intercept-with-geom-smooth) pointed out in the comments, but ... the `ggpubr` function doesn't handle weights (you can confirm this by [looking in the source code](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/blob/6aeb4f701399929b130917e797658819c71a2304/R/stat_regline_equation.R#L137)). Unlike offsets, there isn't even *in principle* a way to pass this information in the formula ...

So, here's an example that uses the weights trick to force the line through 0, fits the line separately, and builds the regression equation by hand. Hopefully it will be sufficient.

```r
dat <- data.frame(time = c(0, 5, 10), perc = c(100, 69, 44))
## add weight values to data; overload first point
dat$w <- c(1e9, 1, 1)

library(ggplot2)
gg0 <- ggplot(dat, aes(time, perc)) + geom_point()
## fit a regression separately so we can use the coefficients
lm0 <- lm(perc ~ time, weights = w, data  = dat)
reglab <- with(as.list(coef(lm0)),
                          sprintf("%1.1f - %1.1fx",
                                  `(Intercept)`, abs(time)))
## using abs(time) because sprintf() doesn't know that a + (-b) is (a-b)
gg0 + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm",
                formula = y ~ x,
                se = FALSE,
                aes(weight = w)) +
    annotate(geom = "text", x= 7.5, y = 100, label = reglab)
```

I don't generally believe in suppressing the confidence intervals. Here they look a bit weird (i.e. surprisingly wide); they don't agree with the way I would more naturally do this, i.e.

```r
lm1 <- lm(perc ~ time + 0 + offset(rep(100, 3)), data  = dat)
predict(lm1, interval = "confidence")
```

so if you do use this method and want confidence intervals, you may have to construct the intervals yourself and use `geom_ribbon()` rather than letting `geom_smooth()` do all the work for you ...

[image]

Comment: This one works. Thanks a lot Ben

Answer (score 1):

Use `lm` with custom `offset` as noted in comments. Then `plot` and add `abline` of the fit.

```
> fit <- lm(perc ~ time, dat, offset=rep_len(-1, nrow(dat)))
> plot(dat, ylim=c(0, 100), xpd=TRUE, pch=20)
> abline(fit, col='blue')
> legend('topright', do.call('sprintf', 
+                            as.list(c('y = %s%sx', 
+                                      signif(unlist(fit['coefficients']), 2)))), 
+        bty='n', text.font=3)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(time = c(0, 5, 10), perc = c(100L, 69L, 44L)), row.names = c(1L, 
3L, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```